# Replace com variavel - mysql

Tags: mysql, variáveis, replace

Como posso fazer `Replace` utilizando uma variável?

Uma determinada `variável` recebe valores de uma consulta, então preciso fazer um `Replace` em uma determinada coluna, com os valores obtidos ,como posso fazer isso? segue exemplo no fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f8f1f/16/0

> Ocorre que os valores obtidos, aparecem como único valor e os
>   resultados não são o esperado

```
 SELECT
@enderecoHashImagem := concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash) as enderecoHashImagem,
@nomeImagem := filename as nomeImagem,
Replace(questiontext, concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',@nomeImagem), GROUP_CONCAT(@enderecoHashImagem)) AS questiontext

FROM mdl_question q 

inner join mdl_files f on f.itemid=q.id

where component = 'question'
```

Comment: Isso esta ocorrendo porque sua variável `@grupoEndereco` esta retornando `null`.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos  no exemplo fiddle esta é saída de @grupoEnderco: `8c/a7/8ca79795dc7c3c7fc836faac6d0d7422627486cb,8c/a7/8ca79795dc7c3c7fc836faac6d0d7422627486cb`

Comment: dois endereços separados por vírgula

Comment: Executa assim: `SELECT
@enderecoHashImagem := concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash) as enderecoHashImagem,
@nomeImagem := filename as nomeImagem, @grupoEndereco := GROUP_CONCAT(@enderecoHashImagem) AS grupoEndereco,
@grupoEndereco, Replace(questiontext, concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',@nomeImagem), @grupoEndereco) AS questiontext

FROM mdl_question q 

inner join mdl_files f on f.itemid=q.id

where component = 'question'` você verá que na segunda vez que usar essa variável retornará `null`.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos vdd, a segunda retorna null

Comment: Será que é possível fazer o que pretendo, usar replace com os valores desta variável ?

Comment: @RobertodeCampos agora não estou mais recebendo `null`, mas o resultado ainda não é o esperado, se puder dar uma olhada, obrigado

Comment: Pra te falar a verdade, nunca utilizei variáveis dessa forma, o que eu faço geralmente é duplicar o código, vou colocar como resposta para você entender melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz o seguinte, faço a consulta usando `group_concat` dos valores que desejo para substuir outros , para obtê-los concatenados separados por vírgulas. Uso o `Replace` e `Substring_index` para, a cada substituição, o valor que já foi usado seja excluído, para determinar o próximo valor a ser obtido uso `Substring_index` novamente.

> Está funcionando, talvez não seja o método adequado, pois se houver
>   mais de 20 valores que desejo susbtituir dá erro, mas até 20 funciona.

Segue sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f8f1f/16/0

```
-- borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/808921

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdl_question` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `questiontext` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `mdl_question` (`id`, `questiontext`) VALUES
  ('1', '<img src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/imagem1.svg"> <img src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/imagem2.svg"> <img src="@@PLUGINFILE@@/imagem3.svg">');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdl_files` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `contenthash` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `component` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `itemid` varchar(200) NOT NULL,  

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `mdl_files` (`id`, `contenthash`, `filename`, `component`, `itemid`) VALUES
  ('1','8ca79795dc7c3c7fc836faac6d0d7422627486cb','imagem1.svg','question', '1'),
  ('2','418679c9ecac4eb42452d4c51332710d24f6de8a','imagem2.svg','question', '1'),
  ('3','418679c9ecac4eb42452d4c51332710d24f6de8a','imagem3.svg','question', '1')

SELECT
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(questiontext, 
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-20),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-20),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-19),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-19),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-18),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-18),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-17),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-17),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-16),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-16),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-15),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-15),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-14),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-14),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-13),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-13),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-12),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-12),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-11),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-11),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-10),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-10),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-9),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-9),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-8),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-8),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-7),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-7),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-6),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-6),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-5),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-5),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-4),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-4),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-3),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-3),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-2),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-2),',',1)),
concat('@@PLUGINFILE@@/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(filename),',',-1),',',1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(concat(substr(contenthash,1,2),'/',substr(contenthash,3,2),'/',contenthash)),',',-1),',',1)) 

AS questiontext

FROM mdl_question q 

inner join mdl_files f on f.itemid=q.id
```

Comment: Sei que deve ter um jeito profissional de fazer mas não sei

Answer (score 0):

Nunca trabalhei com variáveis desta forma, o que faço geralmente quando preciso tratar a informação no `SELECT` mais de uma vez é, duplicar o código, no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
  concat(
    substr(
      contenthash,
      1,
      2
    ),
    '/',
    substr(
      contenthash,
      3,
      2
    ),
    '/',
    contenthash
  ) as enderecoHashImagem,
  filename as nomeImagem,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    concat(
      substr(
        contenthash,
        1,
        2
      ),
      '/',
      substr(
        contenthash,
        3,
        2
      ),
      '/',
      contenthash
    )
  ) AS grupoEndereco,
  Replace(
    questiontext,
    concat(
      '@@PLUGINFILE@@/',
      filename
    ),
    GROUP_CONCAT(
    concat(
      substr(
        contenthash,
        1,
        2
      ),
      '/',
      substr(
        contenthash,
        3,
        2
      ),
      '/',
      contenthash
    )
  )
  ) AS questiontext
  FROM mdl_question q
  inner join mdl_files f on f.itemid=q.id
  where component = 'question'
```

Comment: neste caso o resultado permanece o mesmo, o valores da consulta estão sendo tratados como único valor